# How is new the saiyan in straitjacket from the Dragon Ball Heroes anime called?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

They released a new Dragon Ball Heroes trailer of the new anime and there is a saiyan in straitjacket. Is it known from the videogame or some japanese magazine how this saiyan is called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "evil saiyan"'s name is Kanba/Cumber.

You can find multiple news site talking about it today.
For example [comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/anime/2018/06/20/dragon-ball-kanba-evil-saiyan-name/) and [otakukart.com](https://otakukart.com/anime/dragon-ball-heroes-reveals-the-identity-of-the-evil-saiyan/).
They all reference [this tweet](https://twitter.com/DBReduxTDC/status/1008881964605169664/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fotakukart.com%2Fanime%2Fdragon-ball-heroes-reveals-the-identity-of-the-evil-saiyan%2F).